# como crear una funcion en python que devuelva un numero a partir de la variable tamano y numero de digitos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yo cree la siguiente funcion, pero algo falla, y no se que es:

```
import random
def Numero(tamano, digitos):
   Lista = []
   primer_numero = random.randint(1, digitos)
   Lista.append(primer_numero)
   for i in range(tamano - 1):
          r = random.randint(0, digitos)
          if r not in Lista:
                    Lista.append(r)
          i += 1
   s = [str(l) for l in Lista]
   res = int(''.join(s))
   return res
```

Algo falla en este codigo. una condicion que debe cumplir la funcion es que no contenga duplicados

Comment: No está claro el resultado que buscas. ¿Cual es la relación entre tamaño y número de digitos?

Comment: Si estás dentro de un `for`,  ¿qué sentido tiene incrementar la variable de control `i += 1`?

Comment: La variable tamaño es el número de digitos que debe contar el número. Por ejemplo sería 324 si tamaño = 3. Y dígitos es que dígitos debe contener el número. Por ejemplo si digitos = 5 entonces ese número solo debe contener dígitos del 0 al 4. Otra condicion que debe cumplirse es que el primer dígito no sea 0. Pero algo falla en esa funcion

Comment: Excelente ejemplo de ***cómo no hacer una pregunta en StackOverflow***. La próxima vez que quieras formular una pregunta, te recomiendo especificar ***UN POQUITO*** más que *Algo falla en este codigo*. De ejemplo, te pongo el texto que aparece en la opción para reportar preguntas poco específicas: *Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.*

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es lo que falla?

Answer (score 0):

Sugeriría que crearas una lista con los valores posibles y los vas borrando una vez van saliendo de forma aleatoria. De esa forma no tienes que lidiar con más código del necesario para verificar si un valor es duplicado.

```
>>> p = [2, 4, 7]
>>> r = random.choice(p) # Por ejemplo, 7
>>> p.remove(r)
>>> p
[2, 4]
```

Si en la variable `digitos = 1`, entonces `list(range(1)) = [0]`. Si `digitos = 0`, entonces `list(range(0)) = []`. Por ende se colocó al principio de la función

```
if digitos <= 1:
    return False
```

Luego, el ciclo `while` iterará hasta que la lista esté vacía o hasta que se completen la cantidad de dígitos solicitados `tamano`. Como el primer elemento no puede ser 0, entonces la primera vez, cuando `res == ''`, se verifica que el valor generado es 0, y de ser así, `continue` volverá al principio del ciclo y otra vez generará otro número.

Cada numero generado es añadido a una cadena `res` y luego el mismo es eliminado de la lista original (para evitar la duplicidad)

Finalmente se retorna la cadena convertida a entero.

```
import random

def Numero(tamano, digitos):
    if digitos <= 1:
        return False
    res = ''
    lista_nums = list(range(digitos))
    i = 0
    while lista_nums and (i<tamano):
        elem = random.choice(lista_nums)
        if res == '' and elem == 0: # Si el primer elemento es 0
            continue
        res += str(elem)
        lista_nums.remove(elem)
        i += 1
    return int(res)
```

Una prueba

```
print(Numero(3, 5)) # 410
```

Comment: muchas gracias por las indicaciones. estudiare tu codigo